# SQL statement not valid

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to extract a list froman database based on the following conditions:

"Add below a list that displays the top ten dogs in the show. This is defined as the ten
dogs who have the highest average scores, provided they have entered more than
one event.Display just the dog’s name, breed, and average score."

This is my implementation but it's not working correctly, I'm getting an error message:

```
Select name, breed, score
from

(Select dogs.name as name, breeds.name as breed, avg(score) as score, count(breeds.id) as count
from entries
join breeds on entries.dog_id = breeds.id
join dogs on breeds.id = dogs.breed_id
group by breed
order by count)x
where count >= 2
group by breed;
```

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'u2167487.dogs.name' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I looked for solutions but nothing worked out for me

Comment: Your query is invalid. In your subquery you group by breed, so as to get one aggregated result row per breed. Which dogs.name is it then you want to show? There are many dogs per breed.

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: The top n task lacks precision by the way. When asking for the top n entries, it should always be defined what to do if there is a tie. What if dog #10 and dog #11 both have the same score? Show both (so there are 11 top dogs then)? Show one of them arbitrarily? Or leave them out of the result completely and only show the other top 9 dogs?

Comment: To make this more precise: If nine dogs have each a score of 100, and nine other dogs have each a score of 90, and all other dogs have a lower score. Which dogs would be the top 10? This is not an easy task by the way. The best approach here may be to use `DENSE_RANK` on the average scores.

Answer (score 2):

Your query has many problems.  You seem to want to aggregate by dog and breed and then filter on the count, so I would just do that directly sans a subquery:

```sql
SELECT d.name AS name, b.name AS breed, AVG(score) AS score
FROM entries e
INNER JOIN breeds b ON e.dog_id = b.id
INNER JOIN dogs d ON b.id = d.breed_id
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

The exact error message means you are running MySQL in strict `GROUP BY` mode, and are selecting non aggregate columns which do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  This is not valid ANSI SQL, hence the error message.

Comment: To be precise: If name is unique in the dogs table, then it would suffice to group by the dogs.name to make this valid SQL (as the breed is functionally dependent, each dog has just one breed according to what we see from the datamodel). But in the original query it was vice versa; it was grouped by breed, and it is invalid then to select the dogs.name, for there can be multiple dogs names per breed (in other words: the dogs.name is not functionally dependent on the breed).

Answer (score 0):

You do a SELECT on three fields - but only one field is in the GROUP BY clause.
Add all three fields to the GROUP BY clause or apply aggrigate functions to the fields not included.

When using GROUP BY all your column names must be includede in GROUP BY or have aggrigare functions applied to them.

```
Select name, breed, score
from
(Select dogs.name as name, breeds.name as breed, avg(score) as score, count(breeds.id) as count
from entries
join breeds on entries.dog_id = breeds.id
join dogs on breeds.id = dogs.breed_id
group by dogs.name as name, breeds.name
order by count)x
where count >= 2
group by name, breed, score;
```

By maybe in this example you should use the HAVING clause

```
Select * from 
(
Select dogs.name as name, breeds.name as breed, avg(score) as score
from entries
join breeds on entries.dog_id = breeds.id
join dogs on breeds.id = dogs.breed_id
group by dogs.name as name, breeds.name
having count(*) >= 2
) AS x
ORDER BY "count"
```

Comment: This query gives me this error  :                                                                                            
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as name, breeds.name
having count(*) >= 2
) AS x
ORDER BY "count" LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7" And its also not showing any red errors :(.